# update data in component from Vue.directive

Tags: vue.js

I have a directive that needs to update data in a Vue.component.  How do I set the value?  Here is my code:

```
Vue.directive('loggedin', function(value) {
    console.log('loggedin = ' + value);
    vm.$set('loggedIn', value);
});
```

vm.$set('loggedIn', value) does not work. I get the following error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$set' of undefined

```
var ck = Vue.component('checkout', {
    template: '#checkout-template',

    props: ['list'],

    data: function() {
        return {
            loggedIn: '',
            billingAddr: [],
            shippingAddr: [],

        }
    },
});
```

The value being passed is 'true' or 'false'.

**EDIT**

I need to bind `<div v-loggedin="true"></div>` to my data value in the component and set that to 'true'.  I do not need two-way binding.

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.  Basically, I get a value for loggedin from the server and need to set my loggedIn value to true or false in the data on the component.

Comment: This seems like something you should use an [application-wide store](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) to handle and then just have a [mixin](http://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html) on any component that needs this information

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you are using your directive, so I'm just going to make an assumption. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Have a look at the [`twoWay` property](http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#twoWay) (you would probably need to use the object syntax though):

```
Vue.directive('loggedin', {
  twoWay: true, // Setup the two way binding
  bind: function () {
  },
  update: function (newValue) {
    console.log('loggedin = ' + value);
    this.set(newValue); // Set the new value for the instance here
  },
  unbind: function () {
  }
});
```

Then you can use the directive like this (`loggedIn` is the property you want to write to afterwards, and which serves as the initial value as well):

```
<yourelement v-loggedin="loggedIn">...</yourelement>
```

**Regarding your edit**

Since you only want to pass data from your server to the component, you're much better of just using [props](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props):

```
var ck = Vue.component('checkout', {
    template: '#checkout-template',

    props: ['list', 'loggedIn'],

    data: function() {
        return {
            billingAddr: [],
            shippingAddr: [],

        }
    },
});
```

And then when using your component, pass it:

```
<checkout :loggedIn="true">
    ...
</checkout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go another route.  There had to be a simpler way of doing this.  So, here is what I did.

I am checking if a user is logged in by doing an ajax request through the 'created' function on the vm.  I then update the auth variable in the vm with true or false.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        auth: false,

    },

    methods: {
        getData: function() {

            this.$http.get('{!! url('api/check-for-auth') !!}').then(function(response) { 
                this.auth = response.data;
            }.bind(this));
        },
    },

    created: function() {
        this.getData();
    },
});
```

In the component I created a props item called 'auth' and bound it to the auth data on the vm.

```
var ck = Vue.component('checkout', {
    template: '#checkout-template',
    props: ['list', 'auth'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            user: [],
            billingAddr: [],
            shippingAddr: [],

        }
    },

});
```

And my component

```
<checkout :list.sync="cartItems" :auth.sync="auth"></checkout>
```

Thanks everyone for your help.